# Why does my view disappear when it crosses it's original right and bottom bounds?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a compound view. I have a ImageButton that I want to be able to drag left and right. I can drag it left and up of it's original position and it looks fine. If I ever go right or below it's original position, the button disappears. I have enabled the developer option to draw view bounds. I see that the left and top bounds expand and shrink as I move the ImageButton. The right and bottom do not.

Here it is moving left and up with no problems
[image: Here it is moving left and up with no problems]

Here it is moving beyond it's original bounds to the right, you can see it disappearing as it crosses the right line.
[image: Here it is moving beyond it's original bounds to the right, you can see it disappearing as it crosses the right line.]

I have tried setting new layout params on the button, but saw no change in position. So I'm using setLeft() and setBottom(). Why is my button disappearing?

```
  @OnTouch(R.id.silence_snooze_choice_button)
    public boolean choiceButtonClicked(View v, MotionEvent event){

        //LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) choiceButton.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int)event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int)event.getRawY();

                DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                int width = metrics.widthPixels;
                int height = metrics.heightPixels;

                Log.i(TAG, String.format("%d,%d", x_cord, y_cord));
                //this didn't work.
                //layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord -25;
                //layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                //choiceButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                choiceButton.setLeft(x_cord);
                choiceButton.setBottom(y_cord);

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Here is my layout for my view up top. CircleDragSelector is the name of the compound view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/silence_snooze_choice_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_circle_outline"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the parent layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view_camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_transparent_overlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:alpha="0.85"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alarm_screen_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textColor="@color/accent_material_dark"
        android:text="Alarm name" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alarm_screen_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_screen_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="00 : 00"
        android:textSize="52dp"
        android:textColor="@color/accent_material_dark"
        />



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/alarm_screen_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel_black_48dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Dismiss"
        android:textSize="28dp" />

    <com.example.tyler.rollout.views.CircleDragSelector
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </com.example.tyler.rollout.views.CircleDragSelector>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting clipChildren=false on the parent?

Comment: @BenNeill that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, layouts clip their children, meaning things like negative margins are hidden by default.

Putting

```
<RelativeLayout 
...
clipChildren="false">
```

on the parent layout should fix this.